# Batch file for moving files to specified folder

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I need to move files in several different folders into a common folder using a simple batch file

I have a folder called Export into which the files need to go . FileList contains a list of all the files to be moved saved into a text file files.txt. 
Used the below code but does not work. .

```
set FIILELIST=C:\List\files.txt
set FILESPATH=C:\
set DESTPATH=C:\Export\

for /f %%X in (%FIILELIST%) do call :COPY_FILES "%%X"
goto :eof

:COPY_FILES
for /r %FILESPATH% %%I in (%~1) do echo xcopy /qvs "%%I" "%DESTPATH%%%~pnxI"
```

Comment: What does 'does not work' mean? No files copied at all? Wrong destionation? Wrong files copied? Some error message?

Comment: None of the files were copied. No error message but no output.

Comment: you should show the file list file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version caters for the changed filelist - remove the **echo** after checking.

```
@echo off
set "FILELIST=C:\List\files.txt"
set "FILESPATH=C:\"
set "DESTPATH=C:\Export\"
for /f "delims=" %%X in (' type "%FILELIST%" ') do echo move "%%X" "%DESTPATH%"
pause
```

Give this a burl: remove the **echo** if it does what you want.

```
@echo off
set "FILELIST=C:\List\files.txt"
set "FILESPATH=C:\"
set "DESTPATH=C:\Export\"

for /f "delims=" %%X in (' type "%FILELIST%" ') do (
for /r "%FILESPATH%" %%I in (%%X) do echo move "%%I" "%DESTPATH%"
)
pause
```

Comment: it copies the files successfully.. although , it creates duplicate move statements that fail.. in my files.txt file, i had only 2 file names. It executed the move statement five times per file. What cud be the reason?

Comment: Your file list either has multiple entries (I see now that you mention 2 filenames only) or there are more than one copy of the file in the tree.  That would seem to be likely reasons.  Leave the `ECHO` in there and examine the paths that are being listed.  That should help clarify the reason.

Comment: there seems to be an issue now. . Not all files i want to move are in C:\. all are scattered . Need to tweak it to accept full path of files in files.txt

Comment: Will you have a list of `drive:\path\filename.ext` in the file?